# Haskell desugar syntax

Tags: haskell, syntactic-sugar

Shuklan's [Haskell Lecture](http://shuklan.com/haskell/lec09.html#/0/18) wanted the following code desugared:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter name:"
  name <- getLine
  putStrLn ("Hi " ++ name)
```

I came up with:

```
main = putStrLn "Enter name:" >> getLine >>= \str -> putStrLn ("Hi " ++ str)
```

He revealed:

```
main = putStrLn "Enter name:" >> getLine >>= putStrLn . ("Hi " ++)
```

Never seen that syntax before, how does it work?

Comment: Actually, your style is more accurate in terms of the variables bound, but it could be written either way.

Comment: Your version is the correct desugaring. The given answer does extra work.

Comment: Desugaring does not perform pointfree transformations. The replacement of `\str -> putStrLn ("Hi " ++ str)` by `putStrLn . ("Hi " ++)` is extra work not specified in the desugaring rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The snippets are identical, the latter just uses [point free](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) style (also punningly referred to as "pointless style").

The central point is that `("Hi " ++)` is a partially applied `(++)` that prepends `"Hi "` to the input.

This function is composed (using `.`) with `putStrLn` to get a function that prepends "Hi " to the input and then prints it.

This is exactly what your more explicit lambda does.

Comment: Should have been obvious to me.  Was over thinking it.  Thank You